# Neo4J- Improve LoadCSV relations query time

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a neo4j database with 1 million user nodes. I'm trying to load relationships between these nodes from a 4 million-row CSV file. A user can follow another user. At this point, the query has been running for hours. Is there something wrong with the query that's making it this slow?

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///cleaned_follows_output.csv' AS row RETURN row",
"MATCH (u1 {id: row._s}), (u2 {id: row._t}) MERGE (u1)-[:FOLLOWING]->(u2)",
{batchSize: 10000, parallel: true}
);
```

I have already created an index on the id property by running the following:

```
CREATE INDEX FOR (u: User) ON (u.id)
```

Indexs:

```
Index Name  Type    Uniqueness  EntityType  LabelsOrTypes   Properties  State
index_343aff4q  LOOKUP      NODE    null    null    ONLINE
index_9f2536bf  RANGE       NODE    [ "User" ]  [ "id" ]    ONLINE
index_f7700478  LOOKUP      RELATIONSHIP    null    null    ONLINE
```

Comment: Note that you can actually check if a query is using indexes by running an EXPLAIN of the query. You want to see NodeIndexSeek operators. You do NOT want to see NodeByLabelScan operators. And you especially NEVER want to see AllNodesScan operators, but this is what you will see for this query, since you are not including labels in your MATCH pattern. Without knowing the labels of the node you want to look up, there is no way to use any index, or even a label scan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MATCH` clause must specify the *node label* (in addition to the node property) associated with a node index in order for the Cypher planner to consider using that index.

This query should be much faster:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///cleaned_follows_output.csv' AS row RETURN row",
"MATCH (u1:User {id: row._s}), (u2:User {id: row._t}) MERGE (u1)-[:FOLLOWING]->(u2)",
{batchSize: 10000, parallel: true}
);
```